# Custom Forms do not sync in Outlook with O365

Tags: forms, outlook, office365

I have been using custom forms for a number of years. There appears to be a new issue with O365 and TASK custom forms.

If I open a new task from a custom form, type in a characters, wait 30 seconds and then save it, I get the following error "the item cannot be saved because it was modified by another user or in another window"

So now it tried with the following:

**Test 1:**
I tried the same form in a .PST file and all works OK.

***Test 2:***
Took a standard Task Form - I did not make any changes
Saved the form with the new name “Test1”
Opened the form as a new Task, typed into the Notes/Body field.
Saved
Outlook had the same error. - "the item cannot be saved because it was modified by another user or in another window"
This test has been replicated in 3 different computers.  Same issue.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all related to custom forms - you save an appointment or a task, the OST store uploads it to the Exchange store, its processes the item and stamps its own properties. OST store picks up the server changes some time later and downloads them. If you now try to save an item, you get a conflict.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, Thank you for the process clarification. So how do you suggest that resolve my issue,  since the error only seems to occur with custom forms? Thanks.

Comment: Do not keep an item open and do not call Save multiple times.